# Visual Studio Code move or dock the 'Outline panel' to the right side of the Editor

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, ide, dock, pane

How to move/dock the "Outline" Panel to the right of the editor

```
1. So we can have more "vertical" space in the left for the explorer...<br>
2. and also more "vertical" space in the right for the Outlined items<br>
```

Looks like this should be a pretty standard thing..
(from the editors/IDE(s) I've used)...

but I've been looking through the Visual Studio Code settings...
and also googling this... but no luck yet!

I'm using version 1.47...
but a quick look to the new ones seem not to have this feature...

?Any ideas

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329503/836330

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70645729/836330

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]Ok... it's possible...
and works like a charm...
you just need just 2 "not so evident" steps...

```
1. Move the "Botton panel" to the right...
2. Move The "Outline panel" to the right panel...
```

> ```
> If the "default command line console" is annoying
> just double click the title so it closes to the botton
> ```

And that's it...
now we have a "Full-Size Explorer Panel" at right...
and a "Full-Size Outline Panel" at the left...

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you so much. I have long looked for an option to move the Outline view to the right side and your comment made me realize I simply had to drag'n drop it to the right side for it to attach there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this is an experimental feature in Visual Studio Code.

- Open settings.json
- Add `"workbench.experimental.sidePanel.enabled": true`
- Restart VS Code.
- Drag "Outline Panel" to the right (leaving other panels on the left) and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

From my earlier answer.

An alternative way requires you to run the **Insider Build** of vscode because it enables (experimentally) the ability to add a second Panel on the right - known as the "Side Panel".

`Workbench > Experimental > Side Panel: Enabled`
`Workbench > Experimental > Layout Control: Enabled`
`Workbench > Experimental > Panel Alignment: Center`  `left/right/justify/center`

And then you can drag Views to where you want them (not all views can be dragged and dropped but SCM can).

I know this question doesn't want two side panels, one on the left and one on the right, but given the title of the question people searching for moving a panel to the right may come across this question.

[image: side Panel demo]