# How Do I Have Multiple Panels or Docks In VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I configure VSCode to have multiple sidebar panels?
I want one panel on the left, one on the right and one on the bottom just like IDEA.

I then want to have the Explorer view on the left and I want the Source control view on the bottom.

How do I move the tabs around like this?

The only setting I can find is moving the whole panel from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this is now in v1.64.2.  You can show a new Side Panel either using the "Layout Control" or `View/Appearance/Show Side Panel`.

So for your use case you would show the Side Panel.  It would go to opposite side as the Side Bar.  Keep the Panel on the bottom.  You can drag the SCM icon from the Activity Bar (to the left of the Side Bar) into the the Panel.

And you can drag and drop whatever views you want into the Side Panel on the right.

- from [v1.65 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_65.md#new-layout-control-options)

> #### New Layout Control Options
>
> Last milestone, we introduced the experimental layout control in the
> title bar. We have heard feedback that, while the actions in the
> control are useful, they require too many clicks. For that reason, we
> are adding some options for everyone to try out with the setting
> `workbench.experimental.layoutControl.type`. This setting has the
> following options:
>
> Menu: This is the previous behavior with a single button that opens a
> menu.
>
> Toggles: This is a new option which shows three buttons to toggle the
> panel, side bar, and side panel.
>
> Both: This is a new option which shows the toggles followed by the
> menu button which still allows you to fairly quickly access the
> customize layout quick pick.

[image: Layout Control]

---

Previously:

You can do this but you would need to be running the Insider Build of vscode because it enables (experimentally) the ability to add a second Panel on the right - known as the "Side Panel".

`Workbench > Experimental > Side Panel: Enabled`
`Workbench > Experimental > Layout Control: Enabled`
`Workbench > Experimental > Panel Alignment: Center`  `left/right/justify/center`

And then you can drag Views to where you want them (not all views can be dragged and dropped but SCM can).

[image: side Panel demo]